# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Tags: php, date

its the

$birthDay = date("d", $alder);
$birthYear = date("Y", $alder);

i dont know what it is

here is my code

```
        //Dag
            $maxDays = 31;
            $birthDay = date("d", $alder);
            echo '<select name="day">';
            echo '<option value="">Dag</option>';
            for($i=1; $i<=$maxDays; $i++)
            {
            echo '<option '; if($birthDay == $i){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo ' value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';

        //Måned
            echo '<select name="month">';
            $birthMonth = date("m", $alder);
            $aManeder = 12;
            echo '<option value="">Måned</option>';
            for($i = 1; $i <= $aManeder; $i++)
            {
            echo '<option '; if($birthMonth == $i) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo ' value="'.$i.'">'.$ManderArray[$i].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';


        //År
            $startYear = date("Y");
            $endYear = $startYear - 30;
            $birthYear = date("Y", $alder);
            echo '<select name="year">';
            echo '<option value="">år</option>';
            while($endYear <= $startYear)
            {
            echo '<option '; if($birthYear == $endYear) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo ' value="'.$endYear.'">'.$endYear.'</option>';
            $endYear++;
            }
            echo '</select>';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: parameter 2 ($alder) does not have a valid numeric value. Insert the following line right before the erroneous line and trace back the origin of the current value of $alder:

```
var_dump($alder);
```

You could initialize $alder with 0 or microtime(true) so that date() gets a valid parameter. But if you set it to an empty string ('') you will always get the above error message.

Comment: then a user create a new user the $alder is empty, so it cant be emty?

Comment: `if(!is_int($alder)) { $alder = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this before your failed statement:

$alder = (int)$alder;

Answer (score 0):

[date() function](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects a UNIX timestamp... It seems you are passing in a date as a string.

e.g. 2014-01-10

You should use:

```
$birthMonth = date("m", strtotime($alder));
```